# Azure blob storage not storing locally

Tags: azure-blob-storage, azure-iot-hub, azure-iot-edge

I want to use azure-blob-storage container to store data in a local directory. I have used the upload_blob from another container for this purpose. The file is getting uploaded to the cloud but not getting stored in the local path. I have given binds, device to cloud upload properties and also changed the permissions for the directory with "chmod 777". After doing all this the file is not getting saved locally.

Python function:

```
with blob_service_client.get_blob_client(container=container_name, blob=local_file_name) as upload_client:
 with open(upload_file_path, "rb") as data:
     print("Uploading the file")
     upload_client.upload_blob(data, blob_type="BlockBlob", overwrite=True)
     print("Finished uploading")
```

Binds:

```
"HostConfig": {
       "Binds": [
           "/opt/localstorage/blob/:/blobroot"
       ]
```

Upload properties

```
"blobstorage": {
   "properties.desired": {
     "deviceToCloudUploadProperties": {
       "uploadOn": true,
       "uploadOrder": "NewestFirst",
       "cloudStorageConnectionString": "xxxx"
       "storageContainersForUpload": {
         "bloboutput": {
           "target": "bloboutput"
         }
       }
     },
     "deviceAutoDeleteProperties": {
       "deleteOn": false,
       "deleteAfterMinutes": 15
     }
```

Logs:

```
     [2021-04-20 04:23:57.857] [info    ] [tid 1] Info: Successfully loaded {0}: {1}, p0="Nephos.MaskClientIPAddressesInLogs", p1="False"
 [2021-04-20 04:23:57.857] [info    ] [tid 1] Info: Loading config Param {0} ({1}) read: {2}, p0="NephosIncludeInternalDetailsInErrorResponses", p1="Include internal details in error responses", p2="true"
 [2021-04-20 04:23:57.857] [info    ] [tid 1] Info: Successfully loaded {0}: {1}, p0="NephosIncludeInternalDetailsInErrorResponses", p1="True"
 [2021-04-20 04:23:57.857] [info    ] [tid 1] Info: Loading config Param {0} ({1}) read: {2}, p0="StampName", p1="Stamp Name", p2="Default Stamp"
 [2021-04-20 04:23:57.924] [info    ] [tid 1] Microsoft.AzureStack.Services.Storage.EntryPoint.BlobService: BlobService - StartAsync completed
 [2021-04-20 04:23:57.925] [info    ] [tid 1] Microsoft.Azure.Devices.BlobStorage.Tiering.BlobTieringService: Starting service...
 [2021-04-20 04:23:57.937] [info    ] [tid 1] [BlobInterface.cc:1494] [ListBlobsInOrder] ListBlobsInOrder received. Container:bloboutput BlobNameStart:null MaxBlobNames:1 OrderType:1 Flags:1
 [2021-04-20 04:23:57.937] [error   ] [tid 1] [MetaStore.cc:1953] [ListBlobsInOrder] Container not found. Name:bloboutput
```

Comment: Related Question:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/363624/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Since you mentioned storing files 'locally'. then you should use the method '[download_blob](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-storage-blob/azure.storage.blob.blobclient?view=azure-python#download-blob-offset-none--length-none----kwargs-)'

And this is the [tutorials](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-quickstart-blobs-python#download-blobs).